# WTForms-flask: organize formfield name and data into dictionary

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've been stuck on this for some time now:

I have a form like so:

```
class attributes(Form):
    height=IntegerField('height')
    weight=IntegerField('weight')

class main(Form):
    John=FormField(attributes)
    Ted=FormField(attributes)
    David(FormField(attributes)`
```

I wish to iteratively create a dictionary to store an identifying field label and field data in flask without using `John_height=John.height.data` for every FormField. The idea is to eventually pass the dictionary for writing into a database using a SQL statement where the dictionary key will match the database column and formfield data will be the database values.

The dictionary should look something like this:

```
{John_height : 170,
John_weight: 170,
Ted_height : 120,
Ted_weight: 190,
David_height : 150,
David_weight: 100}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms.fields import IntegerField, FormField

class Attributes(Form):
    height = IntegerField('height')
    weight = IntegerField('weight')
```

To build your forms iteratively you can do either of these:

```
def main(people=['John', 'Ted', 'David']):
    class Main(Form):
        pass
    for person in people:
        setattr(Main, person, FormField(Attributes))
    return Main()
```

or

```
class Main(Form):
    for person in ['John', 'Ted', 'David']:
        vars()[person] = FormField(Attributes)
    del person
```

personally I prefer the second since it is a proper class structure but less dynamic.

To build your dictionary you can then do the following:

```
obj = Main()

data = dict()
for field in obj:  # <- this works since obj has an __iter__ method self defined
    for key in field.data.keys():
        data.update({field.name + '_' + key: field.data[key]})

print(data)
>>> {'John_height': None, 'John_weight': None, 'Ted_height': None, 'Ted_weight': None, 'David_height': None, 'David_weight': None}
```

The `None` values are due to empty form construction.

Comment: everything seems to be working pretty darn good! Thanks! There's only one minor niggling thing in the dictionary. I'm seeing key value pairs like `'John_csrf_token': u'UndnKJnsdknskahks'`, how might I most easily exclude these?

Comment: The simplest way is probably just add an 'if' clause to detect if the 'key' is one you don't want to put in the dict. In this case it's the 'csrf_token' key